# Strange CoreData managedObject Context Save

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode8, ios10, nsmanagedobjectcontext

[Stacktrace of Crash1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5Snq.png)

[Stacktrace of Crash2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgOsY.png)

I am getting these random crashes when I try to delete any record from DB.

Has anyone seen this crash before?

Comment: Are you always getting the crash after deleting the record from DB?

Comment: @Sharpkits thanks for your reply.   its not always happening randomly its happening

Comment: are you getting the crash immediately after updating your DB (i.e tables) structure (not records)?

Comment: No, I am not changing any DB structure without that only am getting this crash

Comment: Does Xcode print any messages in its console when this happens? These stack traces are not useful on their own.

Comment: In Xcode its showing :    [error] error: oid = 0xd000000003200000 <x-coredata://63290A04-5EE1-439D-91B2-1BFC5D5D39E5/*ParentEntity*/p200> [oid class] = _NSCoreDataTaggedObjectID expecting entity *ChildEntity*     

Am deleting the parent entity record

Comment: I will explain you what am doing ,
     I have One entity for example say "Entity A" which has child Entity "Entity B" , Am deleting the record of "Entity A" in that case this crash is happening.

Comment: Any body can help me to fix this crash ?

Comment: When you delete a parent object, are you expecting it to delete any children also, or leave them behind? What Delete Rule do you have set for the relationships? Also please show your source code where you are doing the delete. There's a good chance you have Core Data operations happening in the wrong queue/thread somewhere.